# Installing QGIS from source in Suse Enterprise Desktop 11

Tags: qgis, installation, linux

I have installed QGIS from source in Ubuntu using the [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL) link. In ubuntu I compiled qgis from source without any problem.

but now I moved to Suse Enterprise Desktop 11. In internet every one pointing to [this](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/%3CVERSION%3E/) link. But For Suse 11 there is no repositories available.

So In Suse,

1. how to compile Qgis from sorce?
2. Where can I get all qgis dependency list for suse 11?